# How to use SQLJ with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, eclipse-plugin, db2, sqlj

There is not a plugin for SQLJ. So which files i have to import to project? How can i make the compiler understand SQLJ commands?

I am currently using JDBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new application development environment for DB2 called IBM Optim Data Studio permits to edit from Eclipse SQLJ files.

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-studio/

This application is not open source, but it is free to use.

You can also use several products from IBM Rational that includes this feature.